# What does 's' in visual mode do?

Tags: vim, vi, macvim

I have downloaded a new version of Tim Pope's surround plugin. I noticed he deprecated 's' in favor of uppercase 'S'.

He said this was to prevent interference with a lot of Vim user's muscle memory for hitting lower-case 's' in visual mode. I did some googling but I can't seem to find what exactly this does?

I'd like to know, just in case there is a good bit of info I should know about that key combo :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As described in the Vim manual:

> {Visual}["x]c   or                                      v_c v_s
>   {Visual}["x]s           Delete the highlighted text [into register x]
>   and
>                           start insert (for {Visual} see Visual-mode).  {not
>                           in Vi}

So both c and s do the same thing in visual mode.

Also, in general, if you want to know what a key does in something *other* than normal mode, just prefix the key with the first letter of the mode and a underscore.

For example:

```
:help v_s
```

to find out what the s key does in visual mode.

Answer (score 2):

`s` does the same thing as `x` then `i`

essentially deleting the currently highlighted character(s) then entering insert mode

Comment: thank you. some of this still confuses me, i dont see how that's different from just hitting c... maybe it has to do with my vim config

Comment: `s` works character-wise, whereas `c` modifies a motion command.

Comment: Wow, thanks for a great new shortcut!  To me _s_ now represents the fastest way to modify camel case variable names!  For example: I will now use s to change camelCaseWord to funkyCamelCaseWord!